# Are any stories available for the sons of Sarama that serve Yama?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, animals

**[Sarama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarama)** is the female dog that is mentioned in many Vedic verses as the helper of the gods and is especially associated with Indra. Her children are also mentioned in some verses as being assistants of Yama, the Lord of Death.

**[Rig Veda Book 10, Hymn 14](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10014.htm)** gives us the following description about them:

> 8 Meet **Yama,** meet the Fathers, meet the merit of free or ordered acts, in highest heaven. Leave sin and evil, seek anew thy dwelling, and bright with glory wear another body.
>
> 9 Go hence, depart ye, fly in all directions: this place for him the Fathers have provided. Yama bestows on him a place to rest in adorned with days and beams of light and waters.
>
> 10 **Run and outspeed the two dogs, Saramā's offspring, brindled, four-eyed, upon thy happy pathway.** Draw nigh then to the gracious-minded Fathers where they rejoice in company with Yama.
>
> 11 **And those two dogs of thine, Yama, the watchers, four-eyed, who look on men and guard the pathway,**— Entrust this man, O King, to their protection, and with prosperity and health endow him.
>
> 12 **Dark-hued, insatiate, with distended nostrils, Yama's two envoys roam among the People;** May they restore to us a fair existence here and to-day, that we may see the sunlight.

The description is quite interesting but I wonder if any other scriptures give more details about them. I remember the story in Mahabharata where Janmejaya's brothers beat up one of the sons of Sarama but am not sure if its about the same dogs as these seem quite ferocious!

So my question is - **Do any other scriptures detail the story of these divine dogs who serve Yama?**